# Adding total to another work sheet

Tags: excel, if-statement, worksheet

In Excel, every time a question in column **B** of worksheet `2018 swim` has a value of `yes`, I need that `yes` to be added as a number value to another worksheet to get a total.

Example:
Member is in duplicate program.  If yes I need the yes to be added as a number value under member sheet. So if I have three members that say yes I need those yeses to be placed as three under member sheet in the column that says Total Members that are in duplicate program. Every time a member answers yes it continues to add to get a total in that column.

Comment: So look at a column, and count the occurrences of `yes` in it?

Comment: A simple countif function should get you what you want. `=COUNTIF(A1:A20,"yes")`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=COUNTIF('2018 swim'!B:B,"yes")
```